# A sequence of real numbers with limits as n $\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers:
Assume that $x_n \gt -1$, and $x_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Show that $log(1+x_n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Okay so by inspection this seems pretty obvious since $x_n$ goes to 0 for large n. So $log(1+x_n)$ would just become $log(1)$ which is 0. However I know this wouldn't be a sufficient explanation.

I've been told to use the answer of a previous question as a hint. But I'm not sure how to solve the previous question. Which is as follows:

Let $x \in (-1, 1)$. Show that:
$\frac{x}{1+x} \leq log(1+x) \leq x$

Using the following result: $1+x \leq e^x \leq \frac{1}{1-x}$
I'm allowed to use this result without a proof. But am unsure how to apply it to the latter question asked which in turn means I can't answer the question that I want to. If anyone could offer some insight I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: $\lim \ln (1+a_n) = \ln( \lim(1+a_n)) = \ln(1 + \lim (a_n)) $

Answer (score 1):

The intent of the hint is for you to use the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

As $~x \to 0,~ \frac{x}{1+x}~$ and $x$ both go to $0$.

Comment: So in this case would it be sufficient to substitute $x_n$ for $x$ giving the following:
$\frac{x_n}{1+x_n} \leq log(1+x_n) \leq x_n$ then since both $\frac{x_n}{1+x_n}$ and $x_n$ go to 0. By the squeezing theorem the limit of $log(1+x_n)$ as $n \to \infty$ is 0?

Comment: @IdkWhyIdk Yes, that's it.  However, you should read the Wikipedia article.